# how to find proper driver code in android source code

Tags: android, driver

For example, if I want to find the WIFI card driver source code for Nexus S, what should I do?

It's hard to find the model name of the WIFI card used in specific android smartphone like Nexus S (`lspci` doesn't work, I think).

Can anyone give me a clue? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus S has the codename **crespo**. You can download the platform-specific part by running this command:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/device/samsung/crespo.git
```

Alternatively you could look at CyanogenMod's fork of this project here : https://github.com/CyanogenMod/samsung-kernel-crespo

Which is a bit easier to casually navigate.